# Django & WSGI - Import Error Can't find module django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm setting up a local dev environment in a vagrant box I've configured for django projects.  As such, virtualenv is really not too much use at this point, so I'm just installing everything in requirements.txt with the modules

```
Django==1.7.3
Pillow==2.7.0
django-angular==0.7.10
djangorestframework
markdown
django-filter
mysqlclient==1.3.4
```

My issue is that no matter what I've tried, I consistently get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vagrant/photoapp.com/photoapp/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

The application folder structure is:

```
photoapp.com/
├── app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── photoapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
├── templates
└── Vagrantfile
```

with a standard wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/vagrant/photoapp.com")
sys.path.append("/home/vagrant/photoapp.com/photoapp")

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "photoapp.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and a virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      dev.photoapp.com
    ServerAlias     photoapp.com

    DocumentRoot    "/home/vagrant/photoapp.com"

    alias /photos/  "/home/vagrant/photos/"
    alias /static/  "/home/vagrant/photoapp.com/static/"

    <Directory /home/vagrant/photoapp.com/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/vagrant/photos>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/vagrant/photoapp.com/photoapp>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog        /home/vagrant/logs/error.log
    CustomLog       /home/vagrant/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/vagrant/photoapp.com/photoapp/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
```

But each time I access the site via dev.photoapp.com (hosts file has been modified), I get the error 500 and the traceback message above.

Note that

1. `import django` works from inside a python shell
2. `python manage.py runserver loads up fine with url 127.0.0.1:8000
3. `sys.path` prints out:

   ['',
      '/usr/bin',
      '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
      '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
      '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']

So I can see that the django packages are accessible on the path.  But it's not resolving with Apache access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

`WSGIPythonPath /home/vagrant/photoapp.com`

at the top of your virtualhost config file.